# Set font as bold for rownumbers in rdl(SSRS)

Tags: ssrs-tablix

We have a rdl file in our application where we use it for reporting purpose. Currently, there is a requirement to make particular rownumbers in the tablix to be in Bold format.
We did accomplish this for one row, but we have to do it for a couple of rownumbers.
Please see how we are doing this for rownumber :

`=iif(RowNumber(nothing) mod 13=0,"Bold","Normal")`

The above code makes rownumber 13 to be bold and we need other rownumbers to be bold as well. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Below expression worked :
=iif(RowNumber(nothing) mod 14=0,"Bold",iif(RowNumber(nothing) mod 13=0,"Bold","Normal"))